# 'jarowinkler is not defined' after I run the code correctly the day before

Tags: python, pandas, jaro-winkler

I am getting the following error message:

```
NameError: name 'jarowinkler' is not defined
```

This error comes from

```
from similarity.jarowinkler import JaroWinkler

for word in words:
    df[word] = df.Texts.apply(lambda x: jarowinkler.similarity(x, word)) /* here */
    np.where(df[word] > 0.8, df[word], np.nan)
```

where `words = df.Texts.tolist()`

Yesterday I ran the code correctly and without any issues. 
Any idea on the reason why I am getting this error now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add the following to the script

```py
# call similarity method
jarowinkler = JaroWinkler()
```

- Incidentally, this is in the original script, but must have been missed.

### Alternatively

```py
df[word] = df.Texts.apply(lambda x: JaroWinkler().similarity(x, word))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Trenton. I accidentally deleted and I was not be able to spot it.